# a:nth-of-type(1) not working as expected

Tags: jquery, css

I've the following pseudo HTML layout:

```
<div id="test">
    <ul>
        <li><span><a ...>...</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a ...>...</a></span></li>
        ... <!-- 105 <a> tags in total -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Executing the following JQuery selectors:

```
test = $('#test');
firstItem = test.find('a:nth-of-type(1)');
```

sets `firstItem` to an array of all 105 `a` elements. Why? What's wrong with my selector? Is this a problem with the newest Chrome (using 36.x)?

Expected behavior: I wanted to select only the first `a` element.

Comment: Is this your actual markup? Maybe some widget is applied to the links, and creates a wrapper around each `<a>` element in the process.

Comment: I've updated the pseudo HTML layout to represent more accurately the actual page.

Comment: Why don't you use the `first` selector/method?

Comment: Reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call the children of `#test ul`. It is not `a` but `li`

```
test = $('#test ul');
firstItem = test.find('li:nth-of-type(1) span a');
```

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/bRj5v/)***

I think that you are misunderstanding [nth-of-type<sup>jQuery API</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector)

> Selects all elements that are the nth child of their parent

In other words, it is matching the first anchor child element of each span element, and as a result, you get a very large set.

A better approach would be to use the :first selector

```
test = $('#test');
firstItem = test.find('a:first');
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

> Selects all elements that are the nth child of their parent in
>   relation to siblings with the same element name

The parent of each `<a>` tag is `<span>` and there is only one `<a>` sibling

Try

```
test.find('a').first();
```

Answer (score 0):

it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/x3ztR/

```
test = $('#test');
firstItem = test.find('a:nth-of-type(5)').html("ss");
```

it worked fine to me, debug it using firebug or in firefox press Ctrl+Shift+J and see the error if exist